# Can abstract base classes be used without ProtoInclude if polymorphism is not needed?

Tags: protobuf-net

We'd like to use a base class to make it easy for our RPC responses to have a consistent feel.  We always know what type we're sending over or expecting on the wire, we just don't want to have to declare the same members in every concrete response class.  This seems like it should be possible but doesn't seem to be, without using `ProtoInclude` on the base class.  (The pattern works fine with most JSON serialization, for instance.) Is there, or could there be, a way to use this pattern with protubuf-net?

```
public interface IGenericResponse
{
     bool Succeeded { get; }
}

public abstract class GenericResponse<ErrorCodeEnum> : IGenericResponse 
    where ErrorCodeEnum : struct, IConvertible
{
    bool IGenericResponse.Succeeded
    {
        get
        {
            return ErrorCode.Equals(default(ErrorCodeEnum));
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public ErrorCodeEnum ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string DebugMessage { get; set; }
}

public enum ExampleErrorCode { None, NotFound, }

[DataContract]
[ProtoContract]
public class ExampleResponse : GenericResponse<ExampleErrorCode> 
{
    [DataMember]
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public ExampleData ExampleData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Used in the way shown, protobuf-net will not attempt to look at the base-class, *because it isn't marked as a contract*; as such, `ErrorCode` and `DebugMessage` will not be serialized. So basically (to answer the question in the title): "not if you want to include data from the base class".

Comment: So there is no way to use inheritance (for sharing implementation) without involving protobuf polymorphism?